# Element Hiding Helper stopped working today in Firefox

Tags: firefox, adblock

Ever since it came out, I've used Element Hiding Helper with AdBlock Plus in Firefox.
I have not installed anything, updated anything, changed any settings, or done anything differently with my machine than I have for the past year or so. Element Hiding Helper simply stopped working today.

I have Firefox 24, AdBlock Plus 2.6.6, and EHH 1.3.1.

I still see the menu, and I can still select something to hide. I have Preview enabled in EHH, so I see what the page looks like without what I'm trying to block. But just today, in the last 10 hours, when I either click the element to hide or use the keyboard command "S", the red focus outline disappears, the dialog box disappears, and the element comes right back: it is not hidden.

Has this happened to anyone else, and if so what's going on? Is there a finite number of elements which can be hidden? Because I must have hidden a million items since I installed it.

Any help is much appreciated - I can't stand the internet without EHH.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been a bug in the EasyList filter list that caused this.
See https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=28431 for discussion on the AdBlock Plus forum. It is said to have been fixed, and updating the EasyList subscription will
restore EHH functionality.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and unfortunately, updating the EasyList subscription did not work for me.  I'm trying to block the Google+ notification icon from Gmail and Google Calendar.  I can remove it from Gmail, but it will not remove from Google Calendar, no matter how hard I try.